# How to create a array of structs for matrixes

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc, calloc

Basically I have matrices and want to store them using a struct but I need to do it using dynamic memory allocation

```
typedef struct {
    int mymatrix[5][5];  // the matrix 
    int column;          // will hold column number
    int row;             // this one is for row
} mystruct;
```

so how can i turn this into dynamic memory style?

```
typedef struct {
    int **mymatrix;   // will have the matrix 
    int column;       // will hold column number
    int row;          // this one is for row
} mystruct;
```

is it like this? If so, where do I give the size of mymatrix? I also want to have it as an array of structs but I want to expand that array when new objects are created. Any ideas would be helpful thanks sorry if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Yout `int **mymatrix` will be an array of pointers (rows) to arrays of ints. So first allocate the array of pointers to rows, then allocate the ints of each row.

Comment: Your array of structs can be allocated and reallocated with `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: With these hints you should be able to solve your problem. I assume this is homework so we should not give a full solution.

Comment: You will probably want to store the dimensions of the array in `mystruct` somewhere. Is that what `row` and `column` are for, or are those for some other purpose?

Comment: @IanAbbott they are just gonna show how many rows and columns that matrix has

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks for the answer will look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how memory allocations for your structure can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int **mymatrix;      // will have the matrix 
    size_t row;          // this one is for row
    size_t column;       // will hold column number
} mystruct;

int init( mystruct *s, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
    s->mymatrix = malloc( rows * sizeof( int * ) );

    int success = s->mymatrix != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( i < rows && ( s->mymatrix[i] = calloc( cols, sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL ) 
        {
            i++;
        }           

        success = i == rows;

        if ( success )
        {
            s->row    = rows;
            s->column = cols;
        }
        else
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            {
                free( s->mymatrix[j] );
            }

            free( s->mymatrix );

            s->mymatrix = NULL;
            s->row    = 0;
            s->column = 0;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void fill( mystruct *s, int value )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < s->row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < s->column; j++ )
        {
            s->mymatrix[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1;

    mystruct *s = malloc( n * sizeof( mystruct ) );

    if ( init( s, 5, 5 ) ) fill( s, 5 );

    mystruct *tmp = realloc( s, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( mystruct ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL ) 
    {
        s = tmp,
        init( s + n, 10, 10 );
        fill( s + n, 10 );
        ++n;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < s[i].row; j++ )
        {
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < s[i].column; k++ )
            {
                printf( "%d ", s[i].mymatrix[j][k] );
            }

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( s[i].mymatrix != NULL )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < s[i].row; j++ )
            {
                free( s[i].mymatrix[j] );
            }

            free( s[i].mymatrix );
        }
    }

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 5 

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```